# Empty Data Template in GridView in Windows Store Application (Windows 8 Metro)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I write a program for windows 8 metro style (Windows Store Application). I have a grouped data source which several groups are empty, I'm looking for a way to set a template when a group is empty. I try some WPF solution but I didn't have any progress.

Comment: Use datatemplateselector

Comment: it is not possible dataTemplate is for groups which have items.